# Python: Removing an item from a list based on input()?

Tags: python, list

For one of my assignments there's an offer for extra credit if we can add a new feature that the professor didn't already tell us to do in the assignment instructions. It's a password saver program and I'm saving websites/passwords to a list using a caeser cypher. I'm trying to create a password deletion feature that's based on user specific input.

For example, here's a random template list:

```
passwords = [["facebook", "gGjjI%%%66"], ["youtube", "coYtF###12$"]]
```

Let's say I wanted to delete the password in the passwords list for youtube. I've done some research and it appears that remove() may be a good choice for what I'm trying to do, but I'm having issues putting it into practice.

```
if choice == '6':
    input("Enter the password you want to delete: ")
    for keyvalue in passwords:
        print(keyvalue[0])
    deletePassword = input()

    for i in range(len(passwords)):
        if deletePassword in passwords[i][0]:
            passwords.remove(deletePassword)
```

The issue here is, after I input the website name I want to delete the password for, like youtube in this case, after I hit enter, it reprints the list which still includes what I wanted to delete, and then if I hit enter again, it'll throw: **ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list**

Any suggestions on how to fix this, or pointing me in the right direction on how to do this a better way?

Comment: Is it a must to use a list? Your data structure is better suited using a `dict`, which you can easily remove a key by `dict.pop(key_name)`.

Comment: Henry, I agree, but yes, the assignment requirement is to use list(s).

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
input("Enter the password you want to delete: ")
```

with

```
print("Enter the password you want to delete: ")
```

(you have two `input`s, and you just drop the value of the first one)

Comment: Not really sure why, but this didn't work whereas FabZanna's did. I'm still getting ValueError after replacing input() with print().

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```py
deletePassword = input("Enter the password you want to delete: ")
passwords = [password for password in passwords if password[0] != deletePassword]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to recommend you store the passwords as a dictionary, rather than a list of lists.  This allows you to lookup/access the sites by name rather than numeric index (which gets changed with each modification to the list).

```py
passwords = [["facebook", "gGjjI%%%66"], ["youtube", "coYtF###12$"]]
passwords = dict(passwords)
# passwords is now {'facebook': 'gGjjI%%%66', 'youtube': 'coYtF###12$'}


if choice == '6':
    print("Enter the site name of the password you want to delete: ")
    for site in passwords:
        print(' ', site)
    deletePassword = input('>')

    if deletePassword in passwords:
        passwords.pop(deletePassword)
```